# Using variables in tshark filter in shell script

Tags: shell, filter, tshark

I'm trying to write a shell script that applies a tshark filter on a pcap file. The filter is a variable with characters like '/'.

I have something like

`tshark -r $file -Y "frame contains $PATTERN"`

which works for filters without the '/'. But once `$PATTERN` contains '/', there is an error saying `tshark: '/' is unexpected`.

How do I write the script such that the variable `PATTERN` can contain special characters?

Comment: Can you provide a sample filter that includes a slash?  Are you certain that the filter that is causing the problem is a valid one?  I see that there are valid filter options that include a slash (such as the second example here:  https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters) so perhaps the filter is invalid and the error has room for improvement?

Comment: The filter is a URL, e.g. www.foo.com/bar

Answer (score 2):

Try quoting the `PATTERN`, for example:

```
tshark -r $file -Y 'frame contains "$PATTERN"'
```

On Windows, you would use:

```
tshark.exe -r $file -Y "frame contains \"$PATTERN\""
```

Comment: I've tried that initially, and the command returned nothing. That's when I tried `"frame contains $PATTERN"` which gave me matches for `PATTERN` without the `/`.

Comment: Seems you must escape the double-quotes from within a script:

PATTERN=text/html

tshark -r $file -Y "frame contains \"$PATTERN\""